# iOS converting string to date and time...Eastern Standard Time suffix

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have strings that are being output like so:

7/16/15 10:00 AM Eastern Standard Time

When I try to convert them to dates, using this code:

```
- (NSDate*) convertStringToDateAndTime : (NSString*) strToConvert {

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm aa"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert]);


    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert];
}
```

I get a null result. Do I have to strip of the Eastern Standard Time suffix?

Thanks

Edit: Here's the console log output, first value is NSString trying to convert, second one is conversion result, this is after modifying code as glorfindal suggested.

```
2015-07-16 14:39:07.101 xxxxxxxxxxxx[23685:9316155] 7/16/15, 1:08:00 PM Eastern Daylight Time::::(null)
```

Comment: Try `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm aa zzzz"];`

Comment: Still got a null result

Comment: I see that there are also seconds in your string. You have to add them in the format string as well (`:ss`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure your dateFormat matches the input string *exactly*, including punctuation. The following code parses the date correctly for me:

```
NSString* strToConvert = @"7/16/15, 1:08:00 PM Eastern Daylight Time";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy, HH:mm:ss aa zzzz"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Stupid comma.